# Which Address Locator types use which .cls files?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geocoding

I am attempting to edit the standards file used with ArcGIS 10's geocoding engine. Unfortunately, there are 17 files! As far as [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1113&t=97529) website instructs, there should be an .lot file that tells me which locator type uses which .cls files for their lookup. For whatever reason, I can't find any such .lot file OR anything else that tells me what I need to know. Has anyone else cracked this puzzle yet?

Answer (score 1):

My .lot files are located here: 
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Locators

The .cls files are here: 
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Geocode

A lot file has the code below,  which according to your link is supposed to give you an idea which .cls file to use, personally I had luck with the us_addr.cls file.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
; ESRI Geocoder Optional Properties
;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

FileMAT                = us_addc4.mat
FileSTN                = us_addrc.stn
IntFileMAT             = us_intsc2.mat
IntFileSTN             = us_intsc.stn
```

Comment: These are the exact places I looked, iteration. Great suggestion, but for whatever reason, the only .lot file in that folder is Composite.lot, which reads as a locator template for Composite Address Locator.