# Why ArcGIS turn Front Rd to Frontage Rd

Tags: arcgis-desktop, address-parsing

I did a google search and a search in the ArcGIS forum. Does anyone know why when ArcGIS Desktop standardize an address such as "285 LAKE FRONT RD" and turn it into "Frontage Road"?

It's a fairly small problem but it really shouldn't happen. Right?

Edit: I'm using ArcGIS Desktop but I'm not sure why that would make a difference. I now realize that I should say that when I was standardizing the address field, I was using the US Single House locator.

The problem IS that "Lake Front Rd" is converted to "Frontage Road" after using the Standardize Addresses tool.

Frontage is not recognized by USPS as a street suffix.

Comment: Is "Frontage Road" a category of road?

Comment: This is just a Guess, but the address standardizer is probably converting the Front Rd to Frontage Road. It's something which is internal to ArcGIS, and only ESRI support can help you.

Comment: If you look in USAddress.lot.xml (or whatever locator you're using), you should see a set of aliases for "_front". Frontage is one of the alternatives, so maybe drop it? (after backing up the file!)

Comment: @mkennedy - Thanks! I'll give that a try when I parse the next county's addresses.

Comment: @mkennedy - I just tried to drop "FRONTAGE" from the alias list. I was able to make a copy of the xml file and rename it. But I don't have permission to save to the Locator folder.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me as well.  We were using the older .cls files to create the address locator, and I had to open them in a text editor and modify them.  If you are using .cls files (normally located in C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Geocode), you can search through them for the conversion of Front to Frontage.  I would also point out [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9106/which-address-locator-types-use-which-cls-files).